# unix sed - how to replace multilines with regex

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have some file:

```
aaaaaaaaaa
# Lines Start #
bbbbbbbbb
cccccccc

dddddddddd
# Lines End #
eeeeeeeeee
```

And some variable `$newLines="new line"`
How can I replace the lines from `# Lines Start #` to `# Lines End #` (including those line themselves) with variable's value using sed.

so I'll get:

```
aaaaaaaaaa
new line
eeeeeeeeee
```

I've tried using: `sed -E 'N; s/# Lines Start #\.*\# Lines End #/$newLines/'`
But its not doing it's job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
var='first line\
second line\
third'
# N.B. multilines must end in "\" except for the last line
sed '/# Lines Start #/,/# Lines End #/c\'"$var" file
```

Comment: `c` ``\`` replaces the selected lines with the text. The only caveat that potong rightly stated in his answer is if you use a variable with embedded new lines then they **must** be preceded by a backslash.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way with `sed`:

```
sed '/# Lines Start #/,/# Lines End #/{
/# Lines End #/!d
s/# Lines End #/new line/
}' file
aaaaaaaaaa
new line
eeeeeeeeee
```

- Create a regex range for your pattern
- If it is not the end of your pattern, delete the pattern space
- For the line that is the end of your pattern, substitute with `new line`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` if you like to try it:

```
awk '/# Lines Start #/ {f=1} !f; /# Lines End #/ {print "new line";f=0}' file
aaaaaaaaaa
new line
eeeeeeeeee
```

You can also use range like in `sed`, but its less flexible, so I normal avoid the range function.

```
awk '/# Lines Start #/,/# Lines End #/ {if (!a++) print "new line";next}1' file
aaaaaaaaaa
new line
eeeeeeeeee
```